# Get the ID by Class name JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, input, checkbox

Hi this is a `jquery` question:

supposed i have this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="select" id ="select-1">

<input type="checkbox" class="select" id ="select-2">
```

and i want to **get the id, of the checkbox** that has been selected when i click a submit button (note: you can only select 1)
and i have this button click event here:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

          if($(".select").is(':checked')){

              alert($(".select").attr('id'));
          }
});
```

It **always alerts "select-1"** even if i select the checkbox with the "select-2" id.. I'm guessing since they're both in the same class the first one with the ".select" class to be found is displayed in the alert.. how do i get the specific id that is checked by using their class names? Thank You!

Comment: you should be using radio buttons. if its one option from many = radio buttons. if its multiple options from many = checkboxes.

Comment: Updated my answer, added a demo.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Are you only checking one checkbox at a time?

`alert( $(".select:checked").attr('id') );`

Or, if you have multiple checkboxes checked at once:

```
$(".select:checked").each(function(){
   alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UTux2/

Answer (score 3):

Get ID using this way

```
$(".select:checked").attr('id');
```

Also keep in mind that if only one can be selected, it's better to change it to `radio`.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't capturing the checked checkbox, you're only asking "is there one checked?".

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

    var elem = $(".select:checked");

    if(elem.length > 0){
        alert(elem.attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#submit").click(function(){  
          if($(".select").is(':checked')){
               var $this=$(".select").is(':checked');
               alert($this.attr('id'));
          }
});
```

Comment: `$(this`) points to the `$('#submit')`, so this is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple elements. You need to check for all checkbox having same class

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

          $(".select:checked").each(function(){
           alert($(this).attr('id'));
   });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

you should be using radio buttons and not checkboxes to allow one choice out of many.

```
<input type="radio" name="select" value="select-1">
<input type="radio" name="select" value="select-2">
```

then things will get really simple:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

    alert($('[name="select"]:checked').val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this, you don't need to iterate

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function(){
                  if($(".select").is(':checked')){
                      alert($(".select:checked").attr('id'));
                  }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you have not iterated all the elements which has class 'select'. It always goes to the first element and prints the result. Put a loop to iterate all elements having class 'select'.